Open a folder with a Unicode name in Explorer using Shell
I would like to open a folder with a Unicode name (folder name written in Arabic or Hebrew) from within an Excel file using VBA Shell.
There is no problem to do that with a non-unicode folder name:
Sub Show_Folder()
    Shell "Explorer.exe c:\my_folder_name\", vbNormalFocus
End Sub

but it doesn't work for folder names in Arabic or Hebrew:
Sub Show_Folder()
    Shell "Explorer.exe c:\שם_התיקייה_שלי\", vbNormalFocus
End Sub

The Explorer will open in its default position and not in the directory I specified.

Try wrapping in quotes: Shell "Explorer.exe ""c:\שם_התיקייה_שלי\""",

I did. It still opens in the default position instead of the specified folder.

Shell "Explorer.exe c:\" & ChrW(1513) & ChrW(1501) & ChrW(95) & ChrW(1492) & ChrW(1514) & ChrW(1497) & ChrW(1511) & ChrW(1497) & ChrW(1497) & ChrW(1492) & ChrW(95) & ChrW(1513) & ChrW(1500) & ChrW(1497), vbNormalFocus

Thank you very much. This approach works. Solved.
